# Why would one not stratify random assignments in a controlled trial?

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation

With some frequency I read reports of randomized controlled trials where, despite the randomization, a baseline survey found significant between-group differences in important covariates.

It seems to me that this could be completely avoided with the right sampling scheme--e.g., for categorical features, stratifying and randomly assigning exactly 50% of each stratum to the intervention group.

If this works, why don't more people do it rather than accepting a 5% chance that some important covariate will turn out significantly different at baseline and cast doubt on the study?

Comment: There are several papers that suggest something this. For example, http://scholar.harvard.edu/kasy/publications/why-experimenters-should-not-randomize-and-what-they-should-do-instead

Comment: I wish this were the only common problem with RCTs... Some do use block randomisation. Technically they shouldn't be reporting p-values for baseline statistics in an RCT anyway. These studies should adjust for important covariates in their analyses whether or not the p-value is 'significant'

Comment: IMHO, part of the problem is that actual tests of baseline difference have been done. A *p*-value doesn’t tell us very much, as we *know* that the null hypothesis is true. Also note that apparent bias (lack of balance) on one variable may not *actually* be that much of a problem, as it is often countered by bias in the opposite direction by another (possible unmeasured) variable. (Though I agree that it certainly *can* cast doubt on the results of the study.)

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer: But you *don't* actually know for certain that the null hypothesis is true, right? Sometimes the randomization fails really egregiously ([here's](https://s3.amazonaws.com/bknet/matching/karlan2011.pdf) a recent example I ran across--look at Table 1 for baseline checks. Given that data I would certainly reject the null). In this case I'm very glad they did the baseline checks!

Comment: @BenKuhn No, when random assignment is performed correctly, such null hypotheses must be true. That's the point of random assignment. If there's a big difference between two randomly assigned groups on some variable measured before assignment, that's sampling error. The *population* difference must be 0, because groups are assigned at random. This is not to say that looking at differences between the samples is a bad idea; it's just that hypothesis-testing is the wrong tool, because your concern is with the sample, not the population.

Comment: @BenKuhn You have a point, but if the authors weren’t even able to perform the *randomisation* correctly, I see little reason why one should trust them to perform the hypothesis tests correctly. :) (Though in the cases where they report all the information needed to calculate the *p*-values, one can check that their results are correctly calculated).

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer: in the case of the paper I linked, the randomization may have been performed by a third party (the nonprofit the authors were working with). At any rate, it seems to me that in most situations the analyst, and even moreso the analyst's readers, should never have *complete* a priori confidence that the randomization succeeded, so seeing low *p*-values should still shift your beliefs somewhat towards randomization failing (though of course not as much as if you had no a priori reason to believe the null hypothesis).

Comment: Moreover, if the variables you're stratifying on are also related to the response variable, stratification will also most likely improve your statistical power, correct?

Comment: @BenKuhn Regarding your last comment on statistical power: No, stratification *by itself* (i.e., at the randomisation stage) doesn’t effect the power; it’s the *adjustment* for the stratification variable (e.g., by including it as a predictor in a regression model) that typically will improve the power. And you can and should include important predictors (especially if they are confunders or effects modifiers) anyway. And you get the same improved power as if you stratified at the randomisation stage.